# NavLink in my nav-header is not working when I turn to Mobile view

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, nav

I have problems with a navlink in my Navbar that wouldn't work in mobile view. Problem is I totally don't see what's the problem...

Can someone please help me with this?

Thanks!

Here is my JS code:

```
const Navbar = () => {

function colConCollapse() {
        const colCon = document.querySelector(".container-fluid");
        setOpen(!Open)
        colCon.classList.toggle("collapse")
    }


return(

<div className="container-fluid m-2">
                <div className="navbar-header">
                    <NavLink className="navbar-brand" to="/">
                        <span className="p-2"><img src={Logo} width="50" height="50" alt=""/></span>
                        Newsaggregator
                    </NavLink>
                </div>
                <div className="toggle-collapse">
                    <div className="toggle-icon">
                        <span><Hamburger toggled={Open} onToggle={colConCollapse}/></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <ul className="nav navbar-nav align-items-center mr-4">
                    <li>
                        <NavLink to="/" onClick={colConCollapse}>Home</NavLink>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <NavLink to="/about-us" onClick={colConCollapse}>About Us</NavLink>
                    </li>
                    
                </ul>

            </div>

);
};
```

And this is my CSS code for the mobile view:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 910px) {
  .container-fluid .navbar-header {
    position: fixed;
    padding-top: 8px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    width: 100%;
  }

  ul.nav.navbar-nav {
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
  }

  ul.nav.navbar-nav.text-center {
    text-align: center;
  }

  .nav.navbar-nav li {
    justify-content: center !important;
    align-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  }

   .nav.navbar-nav li:active {
    justify-content: center !important;
    align-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  }

  .nav.navbar-nav li:first-child {
    margin-top: 60px;
  }

  .nav.navbar-nav li:nth-child(2) {
    padding-bottom: 1rem;
  }

  .navbar {
    background-color: #fef7e5;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  }

  .container-fluid {
    flex-direction: column !important;
    justify-content: center;
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    min-height: 5vh;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    transition: all 1s ease;
  }

  .toggle-collapse {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0%;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .toggle-collapse .toggle-icon {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    padding: 1rem 2rem;
  }

  .collapse {
    height: auto;
  }

  .nav.navbar-nav a {
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;

    padding: 0px;
    display: table-cell;
  }

.navbar-brand img {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
  }

.navbar-brand{
    z-index: -1;
}
}
```

I already changed the z-index, because I think/thought it was just the toggle-icon covering the newsaggregator, but that didn't work...

Comment: The CSS appears to do as expected in a copy & paste test. What exactly isn't working?

Comment: Dear Tim R, I can't click the Navlink in mobile view. It isn't recognised as a href when I run it...